# Trying to write an UPDATE comm in a Stored Procedure with Dynamic SQL

Tags: stored-procedures

Here goes, second post, first didn't go to well....

I am calling an SP from a Gridview in ASP. I pass in a table name as a variable along with some other variables. I need to UPDATE my original table that the Gridview attaches to but also build a Datalist, I have used a Fetch and got it working fine. Cycle through those records and INSERT data into third table. I was told (in first post) I need to build the SQL string first then execute it. when I write it that way the second part of the insert does not work.

Here is the code in its sliced up form because of efforts to find a succesfull structure....

```
    @currTable varchar(100),
    @ID int,
    @short_Text varchar(250),
    @brief_Descrip varchar(250) = Null,
    @needsTranslation varchar(10) = Null,
    @prev_LangString varchar(250) = Null,
    @lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @original_lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @StringID_from_Master varchar(250),     
    @GUID varchar(250) = Null

/*

*/

AS        
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @userTable AS VARCHAR(200);
SET @userTable = @currTable
DECLARE @submitDate1 DATETIME;
SET @submitDate1 = GETDATE()



SET @prev_LangString = @original_lang_String
SET @needsTranslation = 'false'

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    -- Establish update to the language tabel of user and prepare to search DB for all strings that will need to be updated.
BEGIN

--  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' UPDATE  ' + @currTable + 
              ' SET [lang_String] = ' + @lang_String + 
              ' WHERE (ID = ' + @ID + ' ';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ID nvarchar(10)', @ID                


        --  UPDATE       @userTable
        --  SET                [lang_String] = @lang_String, [date_Changed] = @submitDate1, [prev_LangString] = @prev_LangString, [needsTranslation] = @needsTranslation, [brief_Descrip] =  @brief_Descrip
        --  WHERE        (ID = @ID)

END

BEGIN               
    DECLARE usedIN_DBScursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT       tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, Database_Name, dbKeyID_ofStringName
    FROM         tblDBUsage
    WHERE        (tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master );


                -- Declare the variables to store the values returned by FETCH.
    DECLARE @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID AS INT;
    DECLARE @dbKEYID as INT;
    DECLARE @dbName as varchar(100);

    OPEN usedIN_DBScursor;

    -- Perform the first fetch and store the values in variables.
    -- Note: The variables are in the same order as the columns
    -- in the SELECT statement. 

    FETCH NEXT FROM usedIN_DBScursor
    INTO @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, @dbName, @dbKEYID;

    -- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    -- Update pending strings table with translation.           
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tblPendingDBUpdates
                                     (stringMasterID, databaseName, databaseStringID, englishText, foreignLangText, submitDate, GUID)
            VALUES        (@StringID_from_Master, @dbName, @dbKEYID, @short_Text, @lang_String, @submitDate1, @GUID);                                       
        END 
--      SET @sql = ''
    -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.
        FETCH NEXT FROM usedIN_DBScursor
        INTO @tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID, @dbName, @dbKEYID;
    END

    CLOSE usedIN_DBScursor;
    DEALLOCATE usedIN_DBScursor;    

END 



RETURN
```

Comment: I see no need for a cursor here, can't you just INSERT all the rows in a single INSERT-SELECT command?? see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263.aspx

Comment: I have to cycle through about 1 to 300 records returned from a tblDBUsage with records that get appended to some of the variables passed into the SP, which then update a third table in teh INSERT. I will check out your link now.

Comment: Still new to this site, please forgive my newbie mistakes.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean and what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Does not work means that the INSERT statement is not inserting data into the table tblPendingDBUpdates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your procedure could be re-written as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procedure_name
    @currTable varchar(100),
    @ID int,
    @short_Text varchar(250),
    @brief_Descrip varchar(250) = Null,
    @needsTranslation varchar(10) = Null,
    @prev_LangString varchar(250) = Null,
    @lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @original_lang_String varchar(250) = Null,
    @StringID_from_Master varchar(250),     
    @GUID varchar(250) = Null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @sql = N' UPDATE  ' + QUOTENAME(@currTable) + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' 
        + REPLACE(@lang_String,'''','''''') + ''' WHERE ID = ' + RTRIM(@ID) + ';';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    INSERT tblPendingDBUpdates
    (
      stringMasterID, 
      databaseName,
      databaseStringID,
      englishText,
      foreignLangText,
      submitDate,
      [GUID]
    )
    SELECT
      @StringID_from_Master,
      Database_Name,
      dbKeyID_ofStringName,
      @short_Text,
      @lang_String,
      @submitDate1,
      @GUID
    FROM
      tblDBUsage
      WHERE tblUniquetblStringsMaster_ID = @StringID_from_Master;
END 
GO
```

However, I am not sure why you need a cursor in your original version, or what you mean by "does not work." Can you explain?

Comment: @KM thanks, I also have many, um, suggestions regarding naming conventions but didn't want to inundate the poor guy.

Comment: Okay I tried this code and am getting an error...[Invalid column name 'test'] which is the value I entered into lang_String, the edit field of the gridview that calls this SP.

Comment: Try now please - not sure how I missed that @lang_String was a string. The syntax highlighting here doesn't seem to like the nested apostrophes. Let's also hope that lang_String will never contain apostrophes or you'll have some really nasty replacing to do.

Comment: Well then I have an issue because I know that there are apostrophe's in lang_String.

Comment: What does "not" mean? Are you getting an error message? Can you be more specific? I've updated for the possible apostrophes but if your insert is simply not running you're going to have to use debugging 101. Does an insert work if you just write a single insert statement with the same values? Is there a trigger on the table? Are you sure it's in the right schema (you should always use schema prefix)? Is this being called in a TRY/CATCH?

Comment: Sure the insert worked fine with the Cursor and I can of course do so with valid data from Mgmt Studio. But as the code appeared before you updated for apostrophes, there was no data being written to tblPendingDBpdates and no error message. The GO though at the end had to be removed I could not save the SP with it listed.  AND THANK YOU for this help.

Comment: What do you mean "could not save the SP"? How were you running the ALTER command? In Management Studio? Without the GO your procedure might have unwanted text that was in the query window after the GO... you should validate that it is only the code you want by using sp_helptext in a query window with results to text.

Comment: When I pasted the code into the SP in VS and tried to save, the GO at the end posted an error. The syntax highlighting indicated that GO was causing the problem. I deleted GO and the SP saved and executed but is still not outputting data to tblPendingDBUpdates.

Comment: VS? You should be altering procedures in Management Studio IMHO. This way you can execute, run other code, etc. all in one place. Anyway I can't tell you from way over here why an INSERT simply isn't working. Did you try removing the insert and just selecting the data, and seeing what the stored procedure outputs? Again, debugging 101.

Comment: VS= Visual Studio. I have used both MgmtStudio and VS, in the end I need to have the code execute as the result of an action in VS, so I do ALL final testing there. Just rather new to this level of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem, but I see one thing that's obviously wrong: In the SQL you're building a string literal is missing its quotes and there's a missing parenthesis. The SQL you're generating would look like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET [lang_String] = lang_string WHERE (ID = 123
```

So it should be:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET [lang_String] = ''' + @lang_String + ''' WHERE ID = ' + @ID
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
UPDATE table_name SET [lang_String] = 'lang_string' WHERE ID = 123
```